# 2 haml link_to on the same line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the haml code template as below:

> %td= link_to "Enable", enable_product(@product)
>   %td= link_to 'Disable', disable_product(@product)

And it display like

> Enable
>
> Disable

But it display in two cell of the table. What I want to display is to put it into 1 cell only. Like

> Enable/Disable Product

Apparently, I still want to get the hyperlink under Enable and Disable.

How I can do that in Haml?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As link_to produces a string, you can concatenate them:

```
%td= link_to("Enable", enable_product(@product))+'/'+link_to('Disable', disable_product(@product))
```

maybe you have to declare the result as html_safe:

```
%td= (link_to("Enable", enable_product(@product))+'/'+link_to('Disable', disable_product(@product))).html_safe
```

Answer (score 6):

The concatenation tip is all good.

Just for the record, here's another method, using HAML's whitespace removal:

```
%td
  %span>
    = link_to "Enable", "#"
  \/
  %span>
    = link_to "Disable", "#"
```

The `>` "eats" the whitespace around the span tags.

Why do we need the spans? Because HAML's whitespace removal only works on actual HAML tags, not on strings coming from Ruby.